Document Duplication and Incorrect File Mappings in ASP.NET MVC Application
We have developed a .NET application where users apply for a certificate, and as part of this process, they need to upload relevant documents that go through a rigorous manual verification process. The application is built using .NET 4.8 with ASP.NET MVC and has been running smoothly for years.
Documents are stored in the filesystem, and the file paths are stored in a SQL Server database within a CertificateDocument object, which is associated with a Certificate object.
Problem:
Recently, we've started experiencing two critical issues:
Document Duplication: Files are being duplicated on the server.
Incorrect File Mappings: Files are sometimes mapped incorrectly, leading to the wrong documents being retrieved.
What We've Tried:
Checked the Code: The application code has not changed in years, so we believe the issue is not code-related.
Investigated Server Replication: We checked for any replication settings on the server and turned them off, but the issue persists.
Reviewed Logs: We've enabled detailed logging but haven’t identified the root cause.
Questions:
What could be causing these issues in an environment where the code hasn't changed?
Are there known issues with .NET or ASP.NET MVC that could lead to file duplication or incorrect file mappings?
What are some best practices for managing files in a filesystem with paths stored in a database?
Would it be advisable to migrate to a different document storage solution, and if so, what low-cost options would be recommended?
Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated!
public void SaveCertificateDocument(int applicationId, string folderName, Models.CertificateDocument document)
{
    var documentType = _db.DocumentTypes.Find(document.DocumentTypeId);
    var documentTypeName = documentType?.Name.Replace(" ", "_");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(documentTypeName))
    {
        throw new Exception("Document Type does not exist! Please check document type standard for valid documentTypeId");
    }

    var documentName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(document.Name) ? $"{documentTypeName}_{applicationId.ToString()}" : document.Name;
    var documentResponse = _documentService.UploadDocument(documentName, folderName, document, applicationId, new TxFileManager());

    if (documentResponse.IsSuccessful)
    {
        var certificateDocument = new CertificateDocument
        {
            Name = documentName,
            DocumentTypeId = document.DocumentTypeId,
            Path = documentResponse.Data.FilePath,
            IsPrintable = document.IsPrintable,
            Extension = document.Extension,
            CertificateDocumentId = document.CertificateDocumentId,
            CertificateId = applicationId,
            BlobPath = documentName
        };
        _db.CertificateDocuments.Add(certificateDocument);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    var data = File.ReadAllBytes(documentResponse.Data.FilePath);
    
    _cloudStorageService.UploadDocument(new CloudDocument { Data = data, ContentLength = data.Length, FileName = documentName}, $"CertificateDocuments/{applicationId}");
}

public Response<DocumentUploadModel> UploadDocument(string documentName, string folderName, CertificateDocument document, int applicationId, TxFileManager fileManager)
{
    try
    {
        //Log
        var data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
        {
            DocumentName = documentName,
            FolderName = folderName,
            CertificateDocument = new
            {
                document.CertificateDocumentId,
                CertificateId = applicationId,
                document.DateCreated,
                document.Name,
                document.MimeType,
                document.Extension,
                document.Path,
                document.DocumentTypeId,
                ContentLength = document.Content?.Length,
                ByteLenth = document.Data?.Length,
            }
        });
        _logger.Log(new DocumentLog{ Data = data});

        //If contains base64 string, convert to byte[]
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(document.Content))
        {
            document.Data = Convert.FromBase64String(document.Content);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(document.MimeType))
        {
            document.MimeType = _mimeTypeService.GetMimeTypeByExtension(document.Extension)?.MimeTypeDescription;
        }

        //If MimeType not empty, get extension
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(document.MimeType))
        {
            try
            {
                var mimeType = _db.MimeTypes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.MimeTypeDescription.ToLower() == document.MimeType.ToLower());
                if (mimeType == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"MimeType specified is not supported for '{documentName}'");
                }
                document.Extension = mimeType.Extension.ToLower();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.Extension = ".pdf"; //TODO: To be changed after project roll out
        }
        //
        if (document.Data.Length == 0) return Response<DocumentUploadModel>.Fail($"No document content");
        var baseDirectory = GetDocumentFolder();
        var documentNameWithExtension = $"{documentName}{document.Extension}";
        var folderPath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, folderName);

        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            fileManager.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
        }

        var filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, documentNameWithExtension);
        fileManager.WriteAllBytes(filePath, document.Data);

        return Response<DocumentUploadModel>.Success(new DocumentUploadModel { FilePath = filePath }, "Uploaded successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Response<DocumentUploadModel>.Fail($"Failed to upload: {ex.Message}");
    }
}


Tbh i dont quite understand how a document (name) is generated. The application id is probably tied to application running? How do you handle duplicate file names in general? e.g. a user uploads the same document twice? I understand that you didn't change any code but why dont you generate a guid for each document and only store the name for displaying purposes?

As you asked for best practices and I can only guess: just generate a guid for each file and store it. This should solve issue immediately if i understand your code correctly
